# Why is linear regression considered an ill-posed problem?

Tags: linear-regression

Could someone please explain to me why exactly linear regression is considered ill-posed?

Comment: This post is somewhat ill-posed. For instance, it would be better with some context. Where have you heard someone claim that linear regression is ill-posed? In what setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem), a problem is well-posed if:

1. a solution exists,
2. the solution is unique,
3. the solution's behaviour changes continuously with the initial conditions.

Now suppose that you have a dataset $(X, y)$ consisting of samples $(x_i, y_i)_{i = 1}^m$, with $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$. I suppose that you think of linear regression as of the following problem for weights $w$ of the regression: $X w = y$ (or something similar depending on how do you stack samples in the matrix).

This problem is ill-posed because of the following reasons:

- the solution is not unique if you have too few samples, namely $m < n$ (for example, there are infinitely many straight lines going through a given point in $\mathbb{R}^2$);
- the solution may not exist if you have too many samples, namely $m > n$ (for example, there are not straight lines going through three given points in $\mathbb{R}^2$);
- finally, there is [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) issue which contradicts the last necessary condition of weight estimates being continuous in observations.

However, the problem can be adapted to fix these properties. Modifying the problem to $\|Xw - y\|_2^2 \to \min$ allows obtaining a pseudo-solution when there is no exact solution (the problem is still ill-posed because there may be many solutions).

You can also add [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) (a.k.a. **ridge** in the setting of regression) to get $\|Xw-y\|_2^2 + \lambda \|w\|_2^2 \to \min$ which allows selecting one solution if there are many solutions of the original problem.